# Pandas Dataframe: I want to merge two cells with same value into one

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

My excel sheet looks like this:-
[image]

I need output in this format:

[image]

Here is the code which I am using to generate the excel sheel:-

```
import pandas as pd

# Create a Pandas dataframe from some data.
df = pd.DataFrame({'Data': [10, 10, 20, 30, 20, 15, 30, 45], 'Value': [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8]})

# Create a Pandas Excel writer using XlsxWriter as the engine.
writer = pd.ExcelWriter('pandas_simple.xlsx', engine='xlsxwriter')

# Convert the dataframe to an XlsxWriter Excel object.
df.to_excel(writer, sheet_name='Sheet1', index=False)

# Close the Pandas Excel writer and output the Excel file.
writer.save()
```

Please help me.

Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is a working example with empty strings in the duplicated `Data` column cells:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'Data': [10, 10, 20, 30, 20, 15, 30, 45], 'Value': [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8]})
duplicated_data = df.Data.duplicated(keep='last')
df.Data = df.Data.where(~duplicated_data, '')
df
```

Will this work for your case?